# Irregular sequence of trade execution in tradingview pine

Tags: pine-script

I am enabling pyramiding=2 in tradingview pine. For every order I am giving a unique id name. Sometimes the order closes with another id, this I am seeing in the list of trades inside strategy tester. Keeping in mind that strategy.position_entry_name gives the name of most recent trade, my logic is when recent trade is LT_2 or when no open trade then open a trade with id LT_1 else open trade with LT_2

```
if (LONG_condition)
    if (strategy.position_entry_name == "LT_2" or strategy.opentrades == 0 )
        strategy.entry("LT_1", strategy.long, when = window(), comment="LT_1")
else
    strategy.entry("LT_2", strategy.long, when = window(), comment="LT_2")

strategy.exit("sell", from_entry="LT_1", profit = close* 0.01/syminfo.mintick, comment="LT_1_sell") strategy.exit("sell", from_entry="LT_2", profit = close* 0.01/syminfo.mintick, comment="LT_2_sell")
```

pine-script

Please see here [Trade list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pS8CF.png)